# When a complete set of representatives is a subgroup (in particular, isomorphic to $G/N$)?

Tags: group-theory

Let $G=C_4=\{e,a,a^2,a^3\}$ be the cyclic group of order $4$ and $N$ the (normal) subgroup $\{e,a^2\}$. Then, $G/N=\{N,\{a,a^3\}\}$, but neither $\{e,a\}$ nor $\{e,a^3\}$ are subgroups of $G$. This made me raise the following questions:

Are there sufficient conditions on the pair $(G,N\unlhd G)$ such that a complete set of representatives of the cosets of $N$ in $G$ forms:

1. a subgroup of $G$?
2. a subgroup of $G$ isomorphic to $G/N$?

---

**Edit**. I interpret the comments as follows:

Let $G$ be a group and $N\unlhd G$. Then, there is a complete set of representatives for $G/N$ which forms a subgroup of $G$ if and only if $G\cong N\rtimes G/N$.

Is that right? (I think I proved this for $G=C_2\times C_2=\{e,a,b,ab\}$ and any of the three (normal) subgroups, where the direct product suffices in this case.)

Comment: You should be able to prove that 2 follows from 1. Then check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product

Comment: 1 and 2 are equivalent, and such a group is called a [semidirect product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product).

Comment: I think the existence of a set is equivalent to $N\to G\to G/N$ splitting (i.e. $G=N\rtimes H$ for some $H\le G$), but unless $N$ is trivial, I think you can never have *all* complete sets of representatives being subgroups - I think this is just a pedantic quibble with how the question is phrased.

Comment: @EthanBolker, means that if 1, then $r\mapsto rN$ is an isomorphism, is it?

Comment: @hal that's right